# How to write from multiple threads to a TcpListener?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Let's say I have a static list `List<string> dataQueue`, where data keeps getting added at random intervals and also at a varying rate **(1-1000 entries/second)**.

My main objective is to send the data from the list to the server, I'm using a `TcpClient` class.

What I've done so far is, I'm sending the data synchronously to the client in a Single thread

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

tcpClient.GetStream().Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
//The client is already connected at the start
```

And I remove the entry from the list, once the data is sent.

This works fine, but the speed of data being sent is not fast enough, the list gets populated and consumes more memory, as the list gets iterated and sent one by one.

My question is can I use the same `tcpClient` object to write concurrently from another thread or can I use another `tcpClient` object with a new connection to the same server in another thread? What is the most efficient(quickest) way to send this data to the server?

PS: I don't want to use UDP

Comment: A TCP/IP connection is logically a sequential stream of ordered data, so it inherently does not support multi-threading. You can have multiple asynchronous writes pending on one connection, though -- those will get resolved in some arbitrary order, which may or may not be what you want. (Usually it's not what you want.) Ultimately, if you try to send faster than the client wants to receive, sends are going to block or fail as the transmission window closes, and no asynchrony will help with that. Check what's actually the bottleneck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345677/tcp-client-through-multithreading-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right; this is a fun topic which I think I can opine about. It sounds like you are sharing a single socket between multiple threads - perfectly valid *as long as* you do it very carefully. A TCP socket is a logical stream of bytes, so you can't use it *concurrently* as such, but if your code is fast enough, you can share the socket very effectively, with each message being *consecutive*.

Probably the *very first* thing to look at is: how are you actually writing the data to the socket? what is your framing/encoding code like? If this code is simply bad/inefficient: it can probably be improved. For example, is it indirectly creating a new `byte[]` per `string` via a naive `Encode` call? Are there multiple buffers involved? Is it calling `Send` multiple times while framing? How is it approaching the issue of packet fragmentation? etc

As a *very first* thing to try - you could avoid some buffer allocations:

```
var enc = Encoding.ASCII;
byte[] bytes = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(enc.GetMaxByteCount(message.Length));
// note: leased buffers can be oversized; and in general, GetMaxByteCount will
// also be oversized; so it is *very* important to track how many bytes you've used
int byteCount = enc.GetBytes(message, 0, message.Length, bytes, 0);
tcpClient.GetStream().Write(bytes, 0, byteCount);
ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(bytes);
```

This uses a leased buffer to avoid creating a `byte[]` each time - which can massively improve GC impact. If it was me, I'd also probably be using a raw `Socket` rather than the `TcpClient` and `Stream` abstractions, which frankly don't gain you a lot. Note: if you have other framing to do: include that in the size of the buffer you rent, use appropriate offsets when writing each piece, and only write *once* - i.e. prepare the entire buffer once - avoid multiple calls to `Send`.

---

Right now, it sounds like you have a queue and dedicated writer; i.e. your *app* code appends to the queue, and your *writer* code dequeues things and writes them to the socket. This is a reasonably way to implement things, although I'd add some notes:

- `List<T>` is a *terrible* way to implement a queue - removing things from the start requires a reshuffle of everything else (which is expensive); if possible, prefer `Queue<T>`, which is implemented perfectly for your scenario
- it will require synchronization, meaning you need to ensure that only one thread alters the queue at a time - this is typically done via a simple `lock`, i.e. `lock(queue) {queue.Enqueue(newItem);}` and `SomeItem next; lock(queue) { next = queue.Count == 0 ? null : queue.Dequeue(); } if (next != null) {...write it...}`.

This approach is *simple*, and has some advantages in terms of avoiding packet fragmentation - the writer can use a staging buffer, and only actually write to the socket when a certain threshold is buffered, or when the queue is empty, for example - but it has the possibility of creating a huge backlog when stalls occur.

However! The fact that a backlog has occurred indicates that *something* isn't keeping up; this could be the *network* (bandwidth), the remote server (CPU) - or perhaps the local outbound network hardware. If this is only happening in small blips that then resolve themselves - fine (especially if it happens when some of the outbound messages are huge), but: one to watch.

If this kind of backlog is recurring, then frankly you need to consider that you're simply saturated for the current design, so you need to unblock one of the pinch points:

- making sure your encoding code is efficient is step zero
- you could move the *encode* step into the app-code, i.e. prepare a frame *before* taking the lock, encode the message, and only enqueue an entirely prepared frame; this means that the writer thread doesn't have to do anything except dequeue, write, recycle - but it makes buffer management more complex (obviously you can't recycle buffers until they've been completely processed)
- reducing packet fragmentation may help significantly, if you're not already taking steps to achieve that
- otherwise, you might need (after investigating the blockage):

  - better local network hardware (NIC) or physical machine hardware (CPU etc)
  - multiple sockets (and queues/workers) to round-robin between, distributing load
  - perhaps multiple server *processes*, with a port per server, so your multiple sockets are talking to different processes
  - a better server
  - multiple servers

Note: in any scenario that involves multiple sockets, you want to be careful not to go mad and have *too many* dedicated worker threads; if that number goes above, say, 10 threads, you *probably* want to consider other options - perhaps involving async IO and/or pipelines (below).

---

For completeness, another *basic* approach is to write *from the app-code*; this approach is even simpler, and avoids the backlog of unsent work, but: it means that now your app-code threads *themselves* will back up under load. If your app-code threads are actually worker threads, and they're blocked on a sync/`lock`, then this can be *really* bad; you do **not** want to saturate the thread-pool, as you can end up in the scenario where no thread-pool threads are available to satisfy the IO work required to *unblock* whichever writer is active, which can land you in *real* problems. This is not usually a scheme that you want to use for high load/volume, as it gets problematic very quickly - and it is very hard to avoid packet fragmentation since each individual message has no way of knowing whether more messages are about to come in.

---

Another option to consider, recently, is "pipelines"; this is a new IO framework in .NET that is designed for high volume networking, giving particular attention to things like async IO, buffer re-use, and a well-implemented buffer/back-log mechanism that makes it possible to use the simple writer approach (syncronize while writing) *and have that not translate into direct sends* - it manifests as an async writer with access to a backlog, which makes packet fragmentation avoidance simple and efficient. This is quite an advanced area, but it can be very effective. The problematic part for you will be: it is designed for async usage throughout, even for writes - so if your app-code is currently synchronous, this could be a pain to implement. But: it is an area to consider. I have a number of blog posts talking about this topic, and a range of OSS examples and real-life libraries that make use of pipelines that I can point you at, but: this isn't a "quick fix" - it is a radical overhaul of your entire IO layer. It also isn't a magic bullet - it can only remove overhead due to local IO processing costs.

Comment: First, a huge thanks for the detailed explanation. The string message will probably have a size around 100bytes - 2500 bytes at the maximum, in a worst-case scenario it may reach up to 3000bytes, but I preferred to keep a buffer size of around 2048 bytes which I thought would be optimal. And no, each message sent so far **has not exceeded** the 2048 range. Great suggestion to use a queue, I'm changing the implementation as I'm writing this.

Comment: Second, the client and the server are the same machine listening and sending from different ports, hence there is no network problem. Hardware, I believe has no issues(i7-8th Gen and 16gb ram) Coming to encoding in the application part, I believe it would slow down the application itself, becuase it has to lightning fast to do the desired opeartions, so I definitely have to use the writer to do the encoding...

Comment: @kowsikbabu on the "lightning fast" ... fair enough I guess, but my thought there was that your machine probably has lots of cores, and if the app-code does the encoding, you are spreading that work nicely; if the *writer* does it, all the encoding is on one core; but - that might be fine. Have you tried the array-pool encode to reduce buffer allocs yet? that might be very helpful. Actually, if you're using ASCII, there are tricks using SIMD for encoding, since UTF16-to-ASCII can be considered as a "narrow" operation - but maybe that's something that should be shelved until you have...

Comment: @kowsikbabu ...better measurements, as frankly ASCII-encode is pretty damned fast already and might not be your bottleneck (plus: the inbuilt API might already be using SIMD/narrow behind the scenes!)

Comment: @kowsikbabu ooh, another though; if you're using local socket communications, and you're presumably on Windows: have you enabled the "fast loopback" socket option? see: https://github.com/mgravell/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/blob/d79dec659594dd9fb630d396e14547f02eb0384a/src/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/SocketConnection.Connect.cs#L62-L80

Comment: if it was me, I'd also be using `NoDelay=true`, but that's when you need to start being really careful with your sends; the default is `NoDelay=false`, which means the `Socket` layer adds a small pause to see if more data will be sent, allowing it to help reduce packet fragmentation at the expense of latency; by taking control of your own packet fragmentation, you can reduce latency, but you need to be careful not to increase the packet count

Comment: you're right, its better do the encoding part in the app-code itself, and about Renting from Shared ArrayPool, I have read at this blog: (https://adamsitnik.com/Array-Pool/#the-results ) that when it comes to smaller array sizes, its pretty much par (**Correct me if I'm wrong**)  and I believe the ASCII encoding isn't the bottleneck!

Comment: Regarding the fastloopback, it sounds good, but only the testing will be done in the same machine, whereas in the real case scenario, the application has to send data to the remote server! Great Info though! It'll definitely be useful for my future projects!

Comment: @kowsikbabu if I knew I was always dealing in smallish buffers, there's actually a third option: `stackalloc` - which will be better than either. The *problem* then becomes how to actually write that, as prior to very recently (.NET Core recent, etc), you need a `byte[]`; in recent .NET Core APIs, you can `Send(ReadOnlySpan<byte>)`, and you can `stackalloc` a `Span<byte>` - put those two things together: no array allocations *or* shared buffer lookup :) https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs#L1239-L1267

Comment: (note: in the `stackalloc` case for optimum performance you'd probably *also* want to disable the locals-init flag, which is hard to do at the moment, but might be added to the compiler soon)

Comment: I'll benchmark both default allocation and SharedArrayPool for data from my application and since I want to be able to support systems running Vista, I'd stick to these two rather than `stackalloc` and would you say this encoding (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1337972/9136356 ) will be a viable replacement for ASCII Encoding? and in the same question is the explanation for how ASCII encoding works

Comment: @kowsikbabu for context - have you seen this? https://www.ageofascent.com/2019/02/04/asp-net-core-saturating-10gbe-at-7-million-requests-per-second/ - Kestrel on .NET Core there running at 7+ million requests/s (server, not client, but... same principles), which is *basically* implemented using "pipelines"; that's part of why I say that you might want to consider pipelines once you've exhausted all the easy options; but : it is inherently "async". The client API for pipelines is lacking, which is why I wrote the unofficial package (linked earlier), which adds the missing pieces.

Comment: @kowsikbabu re Jon's answer: frankly, that is out of date - it pre-dates `Vector`; if I was after a quick and dirty encode, as I say: I'd be using SIMD/"narrow" - that assumes the machines have AVX2 at least, though! But first: you *really* need to ascertain whether the encode is actually a bottleneck; it is easy to get distracted into yak-shaving here.

Comment: @kowsikbabu if you have an upper-bound on your `message` size, another incredibly cheap option would be: just allocate a `byte[]` that is big enough for your biggest possible message, and keep hold of it for the duration of the worker - making sure to encode *into* it, rather than allocating a new `byte[]` per encode

Comment: I'm already using it that way, by using a global static byte[] for the class of size 3000bytes as mentioned earlier in a comment. I've altered the sample in the question to make it understandable! Thank you for providing all the detailed explanation! Appreciate it!